# Use expect to open a new terminal and run command in the terminal

Tags: linux, terminal, expect

from a terminal, I want run a expect script, spawn a new terminal
spawn konsole
then do something in the this new terminal.

I tried 
spawn konsole -e ls
it's won't work

it looks very simple, I just couldn't figure it out.
please help.

here is the script.

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
exp_internal 1
set timeout 20

spawn konsole

spawn telnet 192.168.1.101

expect   "login:"
send "root\r"

interact

expect eof
```

XW

Comment: No can do: expect cannot control GUI applications like konsole.

Comment: konsole is a terminal application. it is GUI application?

Comment: It's a terminal emulator that runs in a GUI window on your graphical desktop.

Answer (score 0):

I am doing

```
gnome-terminal -- expect_connect_script.exp
```

i expect :-)

```
konsole -e expect_connect_script.exp
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I do not see how this answers the question at the top of this page, but it should. Please [edit] according to [answer] or delete the answer. Otherwise it risks being flagged as "not an answer" and being deleted.